# Validate fields for each line, in log file using awk

Tags: shell, validation, if-statement, logging, awk

I'm trying to check filed on log file , line by line. For each line, check if specific filed is empty or field have wrong value .
And print line with the error message

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG=/log/output.log

x=false

    while read -r line; do


            if
              (echo $line | awk -F'|' '{if ($8=="") print "Application is empty"}') ||
              (echo $line | awk -F'|' '{if ($9=="") print "Http request method is empty"}') ||
              (echo $line | awk -F'|' '{if ($7=="") print "Operation is empty"}')
              (echo $line | awk -F'|' '{if ($13 !~ /0|1|2/) print "result(0,1,2) has a wrong value"}')

            then
                    echo $line
            fi

    done < "$LOG"
```

Actual results:

9f2b|EDR|V1|0|V1|2019-05-14|7||||2019-05-14T08:00:40.095Z|1|0|14|19|||XXXXX|||||||||897|||||||||5b8689707|||||||

Application is empty

9f2b|EDR|V1|0|V1|2019-05-14|7||||2019-05-14T08:00:40.095Z|18|0|||||XXXXX|||||||||1234|||||||||5b868007|||||||

Application is empty

42e2|EDR|V1|0|V1|2019-05-14|7||||2019-05-14T08:00:42.532Z|22|0|||||XXXXX|||||||||235|||||||||3b6959ae||||||||

Application is empty

83ac|EDR|V1|0|V1|2019-05-14|7||||2019-05-14T08:00:42.758Z|8|0|||||XXXXX|||||||||789|||||||||5945548f|||||

Expected Result:

Application is empty

Operation is empty

Http request method is empty

83ac|EDR|V1|0|V1|2019-05-14|7||||2019-05-14T08:00:42.758Z|8|0|||||XXXXX|||||||||789|||||||||5945548f|||||

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` reads every line of the file, so there's no need for your while loop with `echo`s.   Just do:

```
awk -F\| ' {b=1}
    $8=="" { print "Application is empty"; b=0 } 
    $9=="" { print "Http request method is empty"; b=0 }
    $7=="" { print "Operation is empty"; b=0 }
    $13 !~ /0|1|2/ {print "result(0,1,2) has a wrong value"; b=0 }
    b
' /log/output.log
```

The main problem with your approach is that the command you are evaluating with `if` always succeeds, so you always print the line.  To make `awk` fail, you would have to add exit statements to each of the awk statements. (eg `echo $line | awk -F'|' '$8=="" {print "Application is empty"; exit 1 }'`

This will print multiple error messages if a line fails multiple conditions, which yours will not do if you add the exit statements and short circuit the `||` operators.

If you want to print only one error message, you could do:

```
awk -F\| '
    $8=="" { print "Application is empty"; next } 
    $9=="" { print "Http request method is empty"; next }
    $7=="" { print "Operation is empty"; next }
    $13 !~ /0|1|2/ {print "result(0,1,2) has a wrong value"; next }
' /log/output.log
```

Or, if you want to print multiple error messages, but all on one line, you could do:

```
awk -F\| ' {s=""}
    $8=="" { printf "Application is empty"; s="; " } 
    $9=="" { printf "%sHttp request method is empty", s; s="; " }
    $7=="" { printf "%sOperation is empty", s; s="; " }
    $13 !~ /0|1|2/ {printf "%sresult(0,1,2) has a wrong value", s; s="; " }
    s { print ""}
    !s
' /log/output.log
```

Comment: thank you , but this code print line that didn't match conditions, and print only error message : ddcd470113f1|EDR|V1|0|V1|2019-05-14T11:36:21.756Z|1|14|POST|/sms/******/requests|2019-05-14T11:36:21.734Z|22|0|||201|https://notif|tel12345|blue|lYS9bAeN7C6gQpUSZeRiXaKL3tShVsH/6Dq3ZNu5BMU=||bin||string|||5cdaa835e9f85739280bb3bf|||||||||||||||||true|AA|AA||||||||
Application is empty
Application is empty
Application is empty; Http request method is empty

Comment: The line you reference in your comment does satisfy the conditions.  Fields 7,8, and 9 are not empty, and column 13 is `0`.

Comment: yes I want to print only lines that match conditions with error messages, and ignore other lines

Comment: In the first solution, change `b`, to `!b`.  In the third, change `!s` to `s`.

Comment: @EdMorton Excellent suggestion!